# Can't go live on Facebook while using Galaxy Camera 2

Tags: camera, facebook

I'm trying to stream a live video using Facebook android app my galaxy camera 2 running Android 4.3.3, but I can't find the "live" option on it.

Is there a requirement for it to work? Will it work if I flashed a CM rom on it?

P.S it's not a regional issue; i can stream just fine using my Xperia Z5 and my galaxy s 5.

Comment: Do you have the facebook app on the camera? Can you even install it?

Comment: Likely an Android version issue. There's no custom ROM for such devices either, so if that's indeed the problem then you have to use another device.